# Convert type from char to string when it's passed by a function

Tags: c, string, stack, atoi

I'm new to programming, while I know there are better codes out there for [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-string/) I sort of don't understand why this isn't working, the value returned by pop2() here is a part of a string which is why for %d it doesn't print the correct value but for %c it does

```
int n = pop2();
printf("n is now %c\n", n);
```

thus even numbers are of string type for **s = "3[a2[c]]"** I want my loop to run the number of times that is returned by pop (2 and then 3 in this case), since the value returned by pop2() is of char type even after using atoi it doesn't work
I tried doing

```
int n = atoi(pop2());
//or even 
char* n = pop2();
int num = atoi(n);
```

but it still wouldn't work, here's the entire code of the function, I've typed out printf statements to help me recognize where I was going wrong, I'd be so grateful if you don't mind helping me out. Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
} *top = NULL;
struct node2
{
    int data;
    struct node2 *link;
} *top2 = NULL;
int isEmpty()
{
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int isEmpty2()
{
    if (top2 == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int val;
    val = top->data;
    top = top->link;
    return val;
}
int pop2()
{
    if (isEmpty2())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int val;
    val = top2->data;
    top2 = top2->link;
    return val;
}
void push(int data)
{
    struct node *new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (new == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    new->data = data;
    new->link = NULL;
    new->link = top;
    top = new;
}
void push2(int data)
{
    struct node2 *new = (struct node2 *)malloc(sizeof(struct node2));
    if (new == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    new->data = data;
    new->link = NULL;
    new->link = top2;
    top2 = new;
}
int peek()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return top->data;
}
int peek2()
{
    if (isEmpty2())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return top2->data;
}
char *decodeString(char *s, char *arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '[')
        {
            printf("pushing s[i] that is %c on stack 1\n", s[i]);
            push(s[i]);
        }
        if (isalpha(s[i]))
        {
            printf("pushing %c on stack 2\n", s[i]);
            push2(s[i]);
        }
        if (isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            printf("pushing %c on stack 2\n", s[i]);
            push2(s[i]);
        }
        if (s[i] == ']')
        {
            if (peek() == '[')
            {
                printf("s[i] is %c and peek element is %c \n", s[i],
peek());
                printf("%c is now popped out next element in stack one is %c\n", pop(), peek());
                if (isalpha(peek2()))
                {
                    printf("element in stack 2 now is %c\n", peek2());
                    char ch = pop2();
                    printf("ch now is %c\n", ch);
                    strcat(arr, &ch);
                    printf("arr after strncating is:");
                    printf("%s ", arr);
                    printf("\n");
                }
                if (isdigit(peek2()))
                {
                    printf("element in stack 2 now is %c\n", peek2());
                    int n = pop2();
                    printf("n is now %c\n", n);
                    printf("current arr is %s\n", arr);
                    while (n < 0)
                    {
                        strcat(arr, &arr);
                        printf("i. %d strncated %s\n", i, arr);
                        n--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return arr;
}
int main()
{
    char s[100] = "3[a2[c]]";
    char arr[10] = {0};
    decodeString(s, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

here's the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vz0q.png) I'm getting, sorry for making this so long

Comment: If you can print it with `%c` specifier, you have a single `char` returned from `pop2`. You might consider that to be "part of a string" but it is not a string in C. On the other side,  `atoi` takes a string, not a single `char`. Your compiler should warn you about that.

Comment: You should add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) together with sample input and expected output as well as real output.

Comment: There is no `string` type in `C`.  There are `string` functions, but a `C` _string_ is defined as a `NULL` terminated array of `char`.  [reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)

Comment: `char n[2] = { pop2(), '\0' };  int num = atoi(n);`

Comment: Agree with [mcve] request in previous comment.  `peek2()`, `pop2()` are not defined here.   They should be.

Comment: thought it would've gotten long so, I'll include my entire code here then if that'd help
I tried `char n[2] = { pop2(), '\0' };  int num = atoi(n);` but it's just getting me a weird symbol
and there was no warning my compiler sort of just skipped that loop part from what it seems like

Comment: @ryyker Re "a `NULL` terminated array of char" --> save `NULL` for pointer contexts, not the _null character_.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, To differentiate, I use `NUL` to refer to the character. That's how char `0` appears in the ASCII standard/charts.

Comment: The terminating character of C strings is `'\0'`.

Comment: `top2 = top2->link;` What happens to the old value of `top2`? You should `free` it.

Comment: Your stacks handle `int` values, but you push and pop `char`. Why don't you make them handle `char`?

Comment: @ikegami To differentiate, I use _null character_ to refer to that character. That's how the C spec calls it.

Comment: Obviously. You already suggested using that. And I pointed out it's official abbreviation, since *null character* is quite a mouthful. It's so unnatural you feel compelled to use italics!